# rhdf5 library in R: reading in file with h5ls

Tags: r, hdf5, rhdf5

I want to read in an hdf5 file in R, but I can't seem to get it to work. The error I'm getting is:

```
h<-h5ls(tsdatabase_path)
```

> Error in H5Fopen(file, "H5F_ACC_RDONLY") :    HDF5. File
>   accessability. Unable to open file.

where h5ls is a method in rhdf5 and tsdatabase_path is an hdf5 file. I looked at this related question, but the solution did not work:

[Error in reading hdf file using h5py package for python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16666066/error-in-reading-hdf-file-using-h5py-package-for-python)

I changed the hdf5 file permissions to `-rwxrwxrwx`. I also looked into checking whether the hdf5 program had been loaded, and I found this in the README.txt in `downloadHDf5` which is part of the rhdf5 package:

> "The rhdf5 package will contain a complete installation of the HDF5 C
>   library. No further downloads from HDF5 are necessary."

My R version is `3.3.0` and my rhdf5 version is `rhdf5_2.16.0`

Comment: Could you print tsdatabase_path ?